# V-model is not binding as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table that iterates over a list of products. For each product in the table I have an input where the user can choose how many units he wants of the product in this row. Then I have another cell in the table for the total which is calculated based on the user quantity multiplied by the unit price. Here is my table.

```
         <table class="table table-striped table-borderd">
                <template v-for="(c, catIndex) in products">
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{c.category}}</th>
                        <th>{{c.bulkSize}}</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="(p, productIndex) in c.productList">
                        <td>{{p.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.productSize}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.productPrice}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input v-on:keyup='calculateTotal(catIndex, productIndex)' type="text" v-model="p.quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input 
                            type="text"
                            readonly 
                            v-model="p.total">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </table>
```

Then in my JavaScript I calculate the total on keyup. Here is the code.

```
calculateTotal: function(categoryIndex, productIndex) {
        let currentCategory = this.products[categoryIndex];
        let currentProduct = currentCategory.productList[productIndex];
        currentProduct.total = currentProduct.quantity * currentProduct.productPrice;
        console.log(this.products[categoryIndex].productList[productIndex].total);
    }
```

The console.log() shows me the correct value but the cell that is bound to total never updates.

I should point out, that both the quantity key, and the total key, are added to the product object through v-model.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: 
Based on answers below I added this code to try and  fix the issue, but it did not work.

```
created: function() {
    $.get('some endpoint', data => {
        this.customers = data.customers;
        this.locations = data.locations;
        this.products = data.products;
        this.products.forEach(cat => {
            cat.productList.forEach(product => {
                product.total = undefined;
            })
        })
    });
},
```

Comment: please create JSFiddle or similar. We will help

Comment: ok working on one now.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hejowapiye/edit?html,js,console,output this is my demo of the issue

Comment: try to:  
        data.products.forEach(cat => {
            cat.productList.forEach(product => {
                product.total = undefined;
            }) 
this.products = data.products;
        })

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by adding `total` property to your products. It may be `0` or even `undefined`, however, it has to be there. It's by design. Related issues on github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1797 and https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3732.

Comment: interesting that you say it has to be declared first. My qty key was not declared first yet it works.

Comment: @usedToBeFat ok, I experimented with it a little more and figured out that binding of uninitialized properties works only one way - when you are entering values. That's why it works for `qty` and it would work the same way for `total`. However, **binding breaks for output** when a property doesn't exist at the beginning. You can try to display `{{p.qty}}` in text (for example next to the input) and you will see nothing even though the entered value comes through to the model.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and works right in with the way I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: http://jsbin.com/nilutegexo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

It was caused by that you are creating list totally dynamically and it is causing issues with reactivity. You have to basically initiate `total: 0` and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: ok so it does work in the jsbin, it does not however work in my app. Can you possibly spot something in my above code that may be wrong?

Comment: this.products.push({id: 1, name: 'foo', total: 0});

Comment: right I added that in mode of the real app and didnt work work. I will edit my question with that bit of code.